# Azure AppService in FreeTier has a status: QuotaExceeded

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, quota

In Azure I got two simple Apps for fronetend and backend in one AppService Plan (FreeTier)

I noticed, that there is a 403 or 404(dont remember) error and status QuotaExceeded. It is a new thing for me.
I checked a Quota tab and look like on attached screen.
It looks like quota it is not reached for both cases but Apps stopped and status: QuotaExcedded. I read a documentation but on graph quota is not reached.

1. Why status is QuotaExceeded
2. Can I reset quota in FreeTier and pay for that? How to do that?[image]
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first picture you can see that you have sent 167,72 MiB of data out of the App Service. The quota is 165, so you have gone over that. It resets in around 6 and a half hours.

You can either wait for the quota to reset, or upgrade the App Service Plan to Shared tier at minimum, which is paid.

Comment: ok thanks, I did not notice 165MiB of limit